# Obtaining JSONP files from Firebase hosting through Angular

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, firebase-hosting

I am trying to obtain a `.json` file from remote firebase server.

```
function fetchData(remoteJsonId){
    var url = "https://myAppName.firebaseapp.com/topics/"+remoteJsonID;
    console.log(url); //This variable expands to the full domain name which is valid and                       returns success both on wget and the browser
    $http.jsonp(url).then(
        function(resp){

        },
        function(err){
            console.log(err.status) // This posts "404" on console.
        }
    );
}
```

But If I open `url` in the browser the json file loads. Even if I `wget url` the json file loads. But through angular it returns a `404` not found.

Now the `.json` remote file has this structure:

```
[
  { 
    "hello":"Europe"
  },

  {
    "hello":"USA"
  }
]
```

The above file can be fetched using $http.get() but not with $http.jsonp(). JSONP cant parse .json file with the above structure. How can I work around this?

Comment: try `$http.jsonp('http://myFireBaseApp.com/MyFolder/JSONFile').then`

Comment: please see the updated link.

Comment: You edit removed the link. Can you please provide a real link (just blank out the name of you Firebase if you feel that is needed)? And can you check the console of your browser to see what URL it ends up calling?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I did inspect what my browser ends up calling. It is the correct link to the json file in firebase. Please help! I am stuck.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25583064

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify a `?callback=JSON_CALLBACK` in the URL that you pass to `$http.jsonp`.

From [Angular's `$http.jsonp` documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#jsonp):

```
jsonp(url, [config]);
Shortcut method to perform JSONP request.

Parameters
Param   Type    Details
url     string  
Relative or absolute URL specifying the destination of the request.
The name of the callback should be the string JSON_CALLBACK.
```

That last line is what you're missing.

A simple example (using a Firebase database, not Firebase hosting):

```
var app = angular.module('myapp', []);
app.controller('mycontroller', function($scope, $http) {
  var url = 'https://yourfirebase.firebaseio.com/25564200.json';
  $http.jsonp(url+'?callback=JSON_CALLBACK').then(
    function(resp){
      console.log(resp.data); // your object is in resp.data
    },
    function(err){
        console.error(err.status)
    }
  );  
});
```

In case you want to see it working: http://jsbin.com/robono/1/watch?js,console

Comment: It is still returning 404. What on earth is happening?

Comment: The link you have provided through jsbin for firebase works. But why not mine? Is some kind of unique setup required to host JSON files on firebase.

Comment: You didn't share your `remoteJsonId`, so I can't be sure. But I highly suspect that you simply forgot to add `?callback=JSON_CALLBACK` to the end of the URL, which is what the first line of my answer says. I did nothing else except the minimum to make your code work. If this doesn't solve it for you, I propose that you set up a fiddle/bin that reproduces your problem.

Comment: I did add ?callback=JSON_CALLBACK. See the edit. There is a new problem now.

Comment: Ok I will do it. Can you look at why jsonp cant parse a .json file with the structure I have mentioned above. Or should I open a new question for that?

Comment: It parses such a structure fine for me: http://jsbin.com/musej/1/watch?js,console. If you keep having that array-parsing problem, open a new question. But only do so if you can give us a minimal reproduction of your problem. So far, I have been unable to reproduce your problems. So: set up a jsfiddle or jsbin showing your problem and it'll be a lot easier to see where you're going wrong and help you.

Comment: Ok. I will do that. Thanks Frank van Puffelen.