# How does $http.jsonp() work

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

Here is an example of a `.json` file:

```
[
  {
     "name":"Jon Skeets"
  },

  {
     "name":"Bill Joy"
  }
]
```

If this json file is obtained as:

```
$http.jsonp(pathToFile).then() {
     ... 
}
```

It returns a 404. There is nothing wrong with `pathToFile` I have verified it with `curl, wget and the browser`. But the problem is with `jsonp()` having to fetch `.json` files with the above structure. `$http.get()` can parse `.json` files with the above structure. But `JSONP` cant. It needs a dictionary at the top level and not an array.

To demonstrate this, I have created this firebase: https://blazing-fire-6512.firebaseapp.com/name.json

fetch the link in your browser or wget and it works. Try fetching it with [Angular here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#jsonp) and it returns 404 Request failed.

Comment: are you  running code using any sever like xampp/django/tomcat?

Comment: @ArpitSrivastava: OP's last problem was on Firebase. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25564200/obtaining-json-files-from-firebase. But I've been able to get such a structure from Firebase using `$http.jsonp` without problems as shown here: http://jsbin.com/musej/1/watch?js,console.

Comment: @ArpitSrivastava Yep I am using Apache.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Please look at the question now. I have done as you said

Comment: How did you put that data into the Firebase? Because your JSON is returned quite differently from mine: https://stackoverflow.firebaseio.com/25564200/array.json

Comment: Hold on... that JSON is **not** in a Firebase. Is it a static file?

Comment: I am using firebase hosting. It is just a static JSON file.

Comment: Yeah it is a static file. Thats what I am saying.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Am I doing something wrong? Should I put this in the firebase database? I did try. That dashboard knackered me.

Comment: Whether you should put certain data in Firebase depends on that data. Firebase is a hierarchical database that automatically synchronizes data (and changes to that data) to connected clients. Firebase hosting is a place to keep static files. If your JSON doesn't change, it is fine to put it in Firebase hosting. Or in any other static hosting place for that matter.

Comment: I am tempted to close this question as a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2067472/what-is-jsonp-all-about. Anyone have an opinion on whether it's sufficiently similar or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebase hosting does not support JSONP. It doesn't handle the `callback` parameter that is used to evaluate JSONP callbacks across origins.

Say you store this JSON at URL `http://example.com/name.json`:

```
{ "name":"Jon Skeets" }
```

If you access the URL  `http://example.com/name.json` you get back exactly that JSON. And that is precisely what `$http.get` does.

When a server supports JSONP, it accepts a `callback` parameter. In such a case the URL ends up `http://example.com/name.json?callback=displayName` and the response is:

```
displayName('{ "name":"Jon Skeets" }');
```

This allows JSON data to be retrieved across origins, which is the whole reason for JSONP's existence.

Firebase's dynamic data servers support JSON. Firebase hosting does not.

Some possible solutions:

1. If you're storing the JSON file **and** the application on Firebase hosting, you can just use `$http.get`.
2. Since you control the JSON file, you can also simply put a function name inside name.json
3. Store the JSON file at a host that supports JSONP. I often put them in Github Gists.
4. Store the data structure in a Firebase hierarchical database, and not on their hosting servers

Comment: any other hosting providers you know that provide JSONP?

Comment: I think you typed that last question in the wrong box. Google is one tab to the right. But I provided at least one options in my latest edit just now.

Comment: Thanks for taking out the time to reply. I wont bug you now. If possible can you please explain the second option. Put a function name inside name.json?

Comment: What does the mean to function name inside JSON?
myFuncName(
 [
  {
  }
 ]
)

Is it like this?

Comment: Yes. It (option #2) simply turns the .json file into a .js file. But why would you not simply go for option 1? If you're on the same server (that doesn't support JSONP), there is nothing against a simple, regular `get`.